# TFlite on raspberry pi - object detection tutorial - Error raised

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, tflite

I am trying to get the following tflite tutorial for raspberry pi running but an error is occuring when executing the `detect.py`

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi

Error:

```
~/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi $ python3 detect.py
--model efficientdet_lite0.tflite
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/alex/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect.py", line 145, in main
    run(args.model, int(args.cameraId), args.frameWidth, args.frameHeight,
  File "/home/alex/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/detect.py", line 86, in run
    image = utils.visualize(image, detection_result)
  File "/home/alex/examples/lite/examples/object_detection/raspberry_pi/utils.py", line 48, in visualize
    category = detection.categories[0]
AttributeError: categories
```

This relates to the utils.py in the repository but i just cannot get it to work properly.
All imported libraries are installed as required, not newer, not older.

When deactivating the follwing part in the `utils.py`, the error does not occur:

```
    # Draw label and score
    category = detection.categories[0]
    category_name = category.category_name
    probability = round(category.score, 2)
    result_text = category_name + ' (' + str(probability) + ')'
    text_location = (_MARGIN + bbox.origin_x,
                     _MARGIN + _ROW_SIZE + bbox.origin_y)
    cv2.putText(image, result_text, text_location, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                _FONT_SIZE, _TEXT_COLOR, _FONT_THICKNESS)
```

how can i get this model to run as intended, with a video stream and boxes including detected category and probability showing in the stream.
when just printing the category and probability in the terminal, it is working fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.